# Change existing app in Heroku to Parse dashboard

Tags: json, heroku, parse-dashboard

I want to change the display mode in Heroku from list (in Json) to table. I do not know how to add Parse dashboard to my existing app in heroku. any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I am looking for here in the article,

http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-the-parse-server-dashboard/

Thank you